# How to bake vertex colors to texture in purely the python API?

Tags: python, uv, texture-baking

Trying to write a python script using only the blender API to convert vertex colors on a mesh to a texture so I can eventually save it to an .mtl file.

How should I go about it? I'm running bpy version 3.4.0

Currently loading the mesh, creating the uv-map and unwrapping it seems to work, but it crashes when trying to set the image to the uv map.
This is what I tried so far:

```
texture_size = 1024 # arbitrary choice

# delete the starting cube
bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube'].select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# import mesh
import_mesh(temp_mesh_path)

# select the mesh
# here load the vertex colors to the mesh
set_vertex_colors(vertex_colors)

# make a UV map and unwrap it
uv_layer = bpy.data.meshes['temp'].uv_layers.new(name='MathTextureUV') # if 'MathTextureUV' not in blendermesh.uv_layers.keys() else blendermesh.uv_layers['MathTextureUV']
uv_layer.active = uv_layer.active_render = True
# unwrap
bpy.ops.uv.unwrap()
# new image to lay over the UV map.
image = bpy.data.images.new('MathTextureImage', texture_size, texture_size)

# creating a new mesh UV https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/how-to-create-a-new-mesh-uv-with-the-blender-python-api/
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
for uv in uv_layer.data:
    uv.image = image      # <-- HERE ERROR: AttributeError: 'MeshUVLoop' object has no attribute 'image'

ob = bpy.context.active_object
VLayer = ob.data.vertex_colors.new(name='MathTextureVColor') if 'MathTextureVColor' not in ob.data.vertex_colors.keys() else ob.data.vertex_colors['MathTextureVColor']
VLayer.active = VLayer.active_render = True
#  bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.context.scene.render.bake_type = 'VERTEX_COLORS'
bpy.ops.object.bake_image()
```

Currently it crashes at

```
for uv in uv_layer.data:
    uv.image = image
```

with error `AttributeError: 'MeshUVLoop' object has no attribute 'image'`

When checking the available attributes to this object with `dir(uv)` I indeed only get the following: `['__doc__', '__module__', '__slots__', 'bl_rna', 'pin_uv', 'rna_type', 'select', 'select_edge', 'uv']` and not 'image'

Comment: Hello and welcome. What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question with code and extra descriptions